# DFDs much larger than a page

Tags: visio

i am designing DFDs for a project management software. One process when split down on level two has too many sub processes with too many external actors. One page is getting too short for designing. What should i do to cop with such situation, Can i use multiple pages for one process description or there is any other suggession? I am drawing in visio.

Answer (score 1):

I searched alot about this question on internet but could not find any solution. But once i discussed with a very senior programmer he told me that we can simply increase the size of page in Page Setup according to the view you require. 
I was facing this issue while designing DMD as well so iutilized this trick on both :)

if anyone has some other better idea then please do share.